# Exclude hidden files in Python

Tags: python, hidden-files

Well, there's a thing I have to do: I have to count files with or without hidden files, with or without recursion, with certain extension or without (it's up to a user)(CLI). The problem is with hidden files.
My method:

```
if namespace.recursive == True:
    for files in os.walk(top=namespace.path, topdown=True): 
        for i in files[2]:
            countF += 1 
    print('Number of files in directory (with recursion): ', countF)
else: 
    p = Path(namespace.path)
    for subdirs in p.iterdir():
        if (subdirs.is_file()):
            count += 1
    print('Number of files in directory (without recursion): ', count)
```

counts files WITH the hidden ones.
**What I want to do:** I want this method to count files WITHOUT the hidden ones. But if a user inputs -h parameter, I want to count ONLY hidden files. So I tried to do a check-method for it:

```
def check_attributes(filename):
    if(os.path.isfile(filename)):
        return win32api.GetFileAttributes(filename) & win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN
    else:
        return 0
```

and then I tried to modify my method and add after

```
for i in files[2]:
```

something like:

```
if check_attributes(f) == 0: #if it's not hidden - then count
```

But it still counts with hidden files. I want to understand how to do it right.
Thank you so much in advance for every answer!
**EDIT:** full function with checking

```
def countFiles():
countF = int(0)
count = int(0)
c = int(0)
try:
    if namespace.extension == '.':
        if namespace.recursive == True:
            if namespace.hidden == False:
                for files in os.walk(top=namespace.path, topdown=True): 
                    for i in files[2]:
                        if check_attributes(i) == 0:
                            countF += 1 
                print('Number of files in directory (with recursion): ', countF)
        else: 
            if namespace.hidden == False:
                p = Path(namespace.path)
                for subdirs in p.iterdir():
                    if (subdirs.is_file()):
                        count += 1
                print('Number of files in directory (without recursion): ', count)
    else:
        if namespace.recursive == True:
            for files in os.walk(namespace.path):
                for f in files[2]:
                    if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == namespace.extension:
                        c += 1
            print('Number if files with extension ' + namespace.extension + ' in directory (without recursion):', c)
        else:
            for files in os.listdir(namespace.path):
                if os.path.splitext(files)[1] == namespace.extension:
                    c += 1
            print('Number if files with extension ' + namespace.extension + ' in directory (without recursion): ', c)
except Exception as e:
    print('Error:\n', e)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Are you sure it makes it past the `if(os.path.isfile(filename))`? This looks right, but it may be failing that check depending on the input string. Can I see an example of what you're passing in?

Comment: @wholevinski yes, sure! I input 'python, *path to .py file* and path to my directory, for example,  D:\Liza\backup'

Comment: Can you try it with forward slashes and see if that helps? It might be interpreting the backslash and the next character as special/escaped characters.

Comment: @wholevinski yes, I tried, but the situation is the same:( But thank you for your help!

Comment: Alright, can you add your hidden files check into your first code snippet and post the whole function? I'd like to try the full code out for myself

Comment: @wholevinski I added it! But I guess it's just me and I just did something wrong and just don't understand what exactly is wrong:) don't waste a lot of time on it...

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try on my windows machine. Happy to help, that's what this site is for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original code, there are multiple boolean args creating different paths. Your `extension == '.'` path was the only one where `check_attributes` was being called from what I can tell, so that *might* have been the issue. I decided to take a crack at rewriting it. The way I rewrote it has 2 phases: 1. get the files, either recursively or not then 2. filter the files with the args provided. Here's what I came up with:

```
import argparse
import os
import win32api
import win32con


def count_files(args):
    files = []
    
    # Get the files differently based on whether recursive or not.
    if args.recursive:
        # Note here I changed how you're iterating. os.walk returns a list of tuples, so
        # you can unpack the tuple in your for. current_dir is the current dir it's in
        # while walking and found_files are all the files in that dir
        for current_dir, dirs, found_files in os.walk(top=args.path, topdown=True):
            files += [os.path.join(current_dir, found_file) for found_file in found_files]
    else
        # Note the os.path.join with the dir each file is in. It's important to store the
        # absolute path of each file.
        files += [os.path.join(args.path, found_file) for found_file in os.listdir(args.path)
                  if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(args.path, found_file))]
       
    filtered_files = []
    for found_file in files:
        print(found_file)
        if not args.hidden and (win32api.GetFileAttributes(found_file) & win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN):
            continue  # hidden == False and file has hidden attribute, go to next one
        
        if args.extension and not found_file.endswith(args.extension):
            continue  # File doesn't end in provided extension
            
        filtered_files.append(found_file)
    
    print(f'Length: {len(filtered_files)}')
    return len(filtered_files)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
    # Note that I took advantage of some other argparse features here like
    # required vs optional arguments and boolean types
    parser.add_argument('path')
    parser.add_argument('--recursive', action='store_true', default=False)
    parser.add_argument('--hidden', action='store_true', default=False)
    parser.add_argument('--extension', type=str)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    count_files(args)
```

Comment: thank you so much, sir! I modified my methods actually so I didn't use your code, but now I know that it's very important to store the absolute path of files, because of you :) Actually, this was exactly why it didn't work, as I found out later. And thanks to your explanation, I worked on it and now everything works okay. Thank you so much for your help, it's so kind of you! You helped me a lot :)